# Different post parameters to rest webservice with jmeter

Tags: java, xml, rest, post, jmeter

I create Thread group , increase the threads to 10 , and use cookie manager in order to get different session while requesting web service , but every time i send same POST parameter to web service , but i want to provide different post parameter in each request to my web service through Jmeter . is it possible ?

Comment: yes its possible, using csv datset config, store the parameter in excel pass that jmeter varieble in post request

Answer (score 0):

Most commonly people use [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) for JMeter tests parameterisation. The idea is the following:

- You have a CSV file containing the list of parameters you want to send
- You add a CSV Data Set Config to your test plan and configure path to your file and output variable name(s), for example `parameter`

  [image: CSV Data Set Config]
- In the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler substitute hard-coded request parameter with the variable from the CSV file like `${parameter}`

  [image: HTTP Request with the parameter]

Now when you run your JMeter test each thread (virtual user) will pick the next line from CSV file on each iteration so all HTTP Requests will be different.

References:

- [JMeter Functions and Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
- [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG)